# Python - Performance when iterating over dictionary keys

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, frequency, large-files

i have a relatively large text file (around 7m lines) and i want to run a specific logic over it which i ll try to explain below:

```
A1KEY1
A2KEY1
B1KEY2
C1KEY3
D1KEY3
E1KEY4
```

I want to count the frequency of appearence of the keys, and then output those with a frequency of 1 into one text file, those with a frequency of 2 in another, and those with a frequency higher than 2 in another.

This is the code i have so far, but it iterates over the dictionary painfully slow, and it gets slower the more it progresses.

```
def filetoliststrip(file):
    file_in = str(file)
    lines = list(open(file_in, 'r'))
    content = [x.strip() for x in lines] 
    return content


dict_in = dict()    
seen = []


fileinlist = filetoliststrip(file_in)
out_file = open(file_ot, 'w')
out_file2 = open(file_ot2, 'w')
out_file3 = open(file_ot3, 'w')

counter = 0

for line in fileinlist:
    counter += 1
    keyf = line[10:69]
    print("Loading line " + str(counter) + " : " + str(line))
if keyf not in dict_in.keys():
    dict_in[keyf] = []
    dict_in[keyf].append(1)
    dict_in[keyf].append(line)
else:
    dict_in[keyf][0] += 1
    dict_in[keyf].append(line)


for j in dict_in.keys():
    print("Processing key: " + str(j))
    #print(dict_in[j])
    if dict_in[j][0] < 2:
        out_file.write(str(dict_in[j][1]))
    elif dict_in[j][0] == 2:
        for line_in in dict_in[j][1:]:
            out_file2.write(str(line_in) + "\n")
    elif dict_in[j][0] > 2:
        for line_in in dict_in[j][1:]:
            out_file3.write(str(line_in) + "\n")


out_file.close()
out_file2.close()
out_file3.close()
```

I m running this on a windows PC i7 with 8GB Ram, this should be not taking hours to perform. Is this a problem with the way i read the file into a list? Should i use a different method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of appearance when you're exporting the frequencies?

Comment: BTW, that `filetoliststrip` function is a bit inefficient, and wasteful of RAM. You read the whole file into a list, then create a new list of the stripped lines. Neither of those lists are necessary. Just loop over the file lines and strip them as you read them.

Comment: I must agree with @PM 2Ring here. In my opinion that is the bottleneck. And you have large files which means everything is kept in the memory. 
Also I would suggest naming your functions a bit better. _thisismymythicialmethod_ vs _this_is_my_mythical_method_

Comment: BTW, it looks like there is incorrect indentation in you `for` loop. Please fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple points that slow down your code - there is no need to load the whole file into memory only to iterate over it again, there is no need to get a list of keys each time you want to do a lookup (`if key not in dict_in: ...` will suffice and will be blazingly fast), you don't need to keep the line count as you can post-check the lines length anyway... to name but a few.

I'd completely restructure your code as:

```
import collections

dict_in = collections.defaultdict(list)  # save some time with a dictionary factory
with open(file_in, "r") as f:  # open the file_in for reading
    for line in file_in:  # read the file line by line
        key = line.strip()[10:69]  # assuming this is how you get your key
        dict_in[key].append(line)  # add the line as an element of the found key
# now that we have the lines in their own key brackets, lets write them based on frequency
with open(file_ot, "w") as f1, open(file_ot2, "w") as f2, open(file_ot3, "w") as f3:
    selector = {1: f1, 2: f2}  # make our life easier with a quick length-based lookup
    for values in dict_in.values():  # use dict_in.itervalues() on Python 2.x
        selector.get(len(values), f3).writelines(values)  # write the collected lines
```

And you'll hardly get more efficient than that, at least in Python.

Keep in mind that this will not guarantee the order of lines in the output prior to Python 3.7 (or CPython 3.6). The order within a key itself will be preserved, however. If you need to keep the line order prior to the aforementioned Python versions you'll have to do keep a separate key order list and iterate over it to pick up the `dict_in` values in order.

Comment: Very very fast, and a lot of useful comments. Thank you!!

Comment: Very neat! Remembering that we store all items, and thus the count is in the length, makes the code a great deal neater.

Answer (score 1):

The first function:

```
def filetoliststrip(file):
    file_in = str(file)
    lines = list(open(file_in, 'r'))
    content = [x.strip() for x in lines] 
    return content
```

Here a list of raw lines is produced only to be stripped. That will require roughly twice as much memory as necessary, and just as importantly, several passes over data that doesn't fit in cache. We also don't need to make `str` of things repeatedly. So we can simplify it a bit:

```
def filetoliststrip(filename):
    return [line.strip() for line in open(filename, 'r')]
```

This still produces a list. If we're reading through the data only once, not storing each line, replace `[]` with `()` to turn it into a generator expression; in this case, since lines are actually held intact in memory until the end of the program, we'd only save the space for the list (which is still at least 30MB in your case).

Then we have the main parsing loop (I adjusted the indentation as I thought it should be):

```
counter = 0

for line in fileinlist:
    counter += 1
    keyf = line[10:69]
    print("Loading line " + str(counter) + " : " + str(line))
    if keyf not in dict_in.keys():
        dict_in[keyf] = []
        dict_in[keyf].append(1)
        dict_in[keyf].append(line)
    else:
        dict_in[keyf][0] += 1
        dict_in[keyf].append(line)
```

There are several suboptimal things here.

First, the counter could be an `enumerate` (when you don't have an iterable, there's `range` or `itertools.count`). Changing this will help with clarity and reduce the risk of mistakes.

```
for counter, line in enumerate(fileinlist, 1):
```

Second, it's more efficient to form a string in one operation than add it from bits:

```
    print("Loading line {} : {}".format(counter, line))
```

Third, there's no need to extract the keys for a dictionary member check. In Python 2 that builds a new list, which means copying all the references held in the keys, and gets slower with every iteration. In Python 3, it still means building a key view object needlessly. Just use `keyf not in dict_in` if the check is needed.

Fourth, the check really isn't needed. Catching the exception when a lookup fails is pretty much as fast as the if check, and repeating the lookup after the if check is almost certainly slower. For that matter, stop repeating lookups in general:

```
    try:
        dictvalue = dict_in[keyf]
        dictvalue[0] += 1
        dictvalue.append(line)
    except KeyError:
        dict_in[keyf] = [1, line]
```

This is such a common pattern, however, that we have *two* standard library implementations of it: `Counter` and `defaultdict`. We could use both here, but the Counter is more practical when you only want the count.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def newentry():
    return [0]
dict_in = defaultdict(newentry)

for counter, line in enumerate(fileinlist, 1):
    keyf = line[10:69]
    print("Loading line {} : {}".format(counter, line))
    dictvalue = dict_in[keyf]
    dictvalue[0] += 1
    dictvalue.append(line)
```

Using `defaultdict` let us not worry about whether the entries existed or not.

We now arrive at the output phase. Again we have needless lookups, so let's reduce them to one iteration:

```
for key, value in dict_in.iteritems():  # just items() in Python 3
    print("Processing key: " + key)
    #print(value)
    count, lines = value[0], value[1:]
    if count < 2:
        out_file.write(lines[0])
    elif count == 2:
        for line_in in lines:
            out_file2.write(line_in + "\n")
    elif count > 2:
        for line_in in lines:
            out_file3.write(line_in + "\n")
```

That still has a few annoyances. We've repeated the writing code, it builds other strings (tagging on `"\n"`), and it has a whole chunk of similar code for each case. In fact, the repetition probably caused a bug: there's no newline separator for the single occurrences in `out_file`. Let's factor out what really differs:

```
for key, value in dict_in.iteritems():  # just items() in Python 3
    print("Processing key: " + key)
    #print(value)
    count, lines = value[0], value[1:]
    if count < 2:
        key_outf = out_file
    elif count == 2:
        key_outf = out_file2
    else:  #  elif count > 2:  # Test not needed
        key_outf = out_file3
    key_outf.writelines(line_in + "\n" for line_in in lines)
```

I've left the newline concatenation because it's more complex to mix them in as separate calls. The string is short-lived and it serves a purpose to have the newline in the same place: it makes it less likely at OS level that a line is broken up by concurrent writes.

You'll have noticed there are Python 2 and 3 differences here. Most likely your code wasn't all that slow if run in Python 3 in the first place. There exists a compatibility module called [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/) to write code that more easily runs in either; it lets you use e.g. `six.viewkeys` and `six.iteritems` to avoid this gotcha.

Answer (score 0):

You load a very large file onto memory at once. When you don't actually needs the lines, and you just need to process it, use a *generator*. It is more memory-efficient.

`Counter` is a collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. You can use that to count the frequency of the keys. Then simply iterate over the new `dict` and append the key to the relevant file:

```
from collections import Counter

keys = ['A1KEY1', 'A2KEY1', 'B1KEY2', 'C1KEY3', 'D1KEY3', 'E1KEY4']
count = Counter(keys)


with open('single.txt') as f1:
    with open('double.txt') as f2:
        with open('more_than_double.txt') as f3:

        for k, v in count.items():
            if v == 1:
                f1.writelines(k)
            elif v == 2:
                f2.writelines(k)
            else:
                f3.writelines(k)
```